# Resource pooling in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, connection-pool

As an exercise, and in an effort to avoid wrapping callback APIs in every node library it seems, I threw together a resource pool class. The intended usage is the following:

```
const pool = new Pool({
  createConnection() { return ... Promise<MyConnection> }
  destroyConnection(c: MyConnection) { return ... any }
})

const connection = await pool.resource()

//later...
pool.release(connection)

//maybe if error occurs in handlers setup in `createConnection`
pool.destroy(connection)

//and when finished
pool.drain().then(() => pool.close())
```

My goal is for the behavior to be as unsurprising as possible. And I'd like feedback!

Here is a link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/calebboyd/ac6cd8e6bda8c6c1626696aa9cbd915e).

```
import Queue from 'double-ended-queue'

const POOL_ID = Symbol('pool-id')
const IS_DIRTY = Symbol('dirty')

function isDirty (resource) {
  return resource[IS_DIRTY]
}

function poolId (resource) {
  return resource[POOL_ID]
}

function range (num) {
  return Array.from(Array(num))
}

class Deferred<T> {
  public promise: Promise<T>
  public resolve: (answer: T) => void
  public reject: (error: Error) => void
  constructor () {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve
      this.reject = reject
    })
  }
}

function isDefined (thing: any) {
  return typeof thing !== 'undefined'
}

class Pool<T> {
  private _closing = false
  private _min: number = 0
  private _max: number = 10
  private _idle: number = 30000
  private _resourceIds: Queue<number>
  private _resources: Queue<{ expiration: number, resource: T}>
  private _issued: { [key: string]: T } = {}
  private _pending: Queue<Deferred<T>> = new Queue<Deferred<T>>()
  private _timeoutToken: any
  private _size: number = 0
  private _initializing = false
  private _createResource: () => Promise<T>
  private _destroyResource: (resource: T) => Promise<any>
  constructor ({ createConnection, destroyConnection, idle, min, max }) {
    this._max = max || this._max
    this._min = min || this._min
    this._idle = idle || this._idle
    this._resources = new Queue<{ expiration: number, resource: T}>(max)
    this._createResource = () => {
      this._size++
      return Promise.resolve(createConnection())
    }  
    this._destroyResource = (x) => {
      this._size--
      return Promise.resolve(destroyConnection(x))
    }
    this._resourceIds = new Queue(range(this.max).map((_, i) => 1 + i))

    if (this.min > 0) {
      this._initializing = true
      Promise.all(range(this.min).map(this._createResource))
      .then(resources => {
        this._resources.enqueue(
          ...resources.map(resource => ({ expiration: Date.now(), resource }))
        )
        this._pending.toArray().forEach(x => x.resolve(this.resource()))
        this._initializing = false
        this._pending.clear()
      })
    }
  }

  /**
   * Current number of resources in pool
   */
  public get size () { return this._size }

  /**
   * Current number of resources in use
   */
  public get issued () { return this.max - this._resourceIds.length }

  /**
   * Maximum size of pool
   */
  public get max () { return this._max }

  /**
   * Minimum size of pool
   */
  public get min () { return this._min }

  /**
   * Approximate lifetime (ms) of an unused resource
   */
  public get idle () { return this._idle }

  /**
   * Forcibly destroy all created resources
   * To close the pool gracefully, call #drain first
   * A subsequent call to #resource is a programming error  
   */
  public close () {
    this._closing = true
    return Promise.all(Object.keys(this._issued)
      .map(x => this._issued[x])
      .concat(this._resources.toArray().map(x => x.resource))
      .map(x => this.destroy(x)))
  }
  /**
   * Wait until all resources have been released
   * This will not prevent resources from being issued. (calls to #resource)
   * Usually followed by a call to #close.
   * Calling close while draining, will short circuit this process
   */
  public drain () {
    return new Promise ((resolve) => {
      !function wait () {
        if (this.issued === 0) {
          resolve()
        } else {
          !this._closing && setTimeout(wait, 100) || resolve()
        } 
      }()
    })
  }

  /**
   * Destroy a resource. This is useful if you deterime the resource is in an error state.
   * It can be called at any time. 
   * If a destroyed resource is currently issued it will also be released
   */
  public destroy (resource) {
    if (isDirty(resource)) {
      return Promise.resolve()
    }
    resource[IS_DIRTY] = true
    if (poolId(resource)) {
      this.release(resource)
    }

    return this._destroyResource(resource)
  }

  /**
   * Immediately release a resource back into the pool. 
   * If the resource has not also been destroyed it may be recycled immediately.
   * Released resources that remain unused for #idle milliseconds will be destroyed.
   */
  public release (resource) {
    const resourceId = poolId(resource)

    if (!isDirty(resource) && this._pending.length) {
      return this._pending.dequeue().resolve(resource)
    }
    delete this._issued[resourceId]
    delete resource[POOL_ID]

    this._resourceIds.enqueue(resourceId)
    !isDirty(resource) && this._queuePossibleDestruction(resource)
  }

  /**
   * Request a resource, if none exist, request will be queued or one will be created. 
   * Otherwise, previously released resources are issued.
   */
  public resource () {
    if (this._closing) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Cannot issue resource while pool is closing...'))
    }

    if (!this._resourceIds.length || this._initializing) {
      const futureAvailableResource = new Deferred<T>()
      this._pending.enqueue(futureAvailableResource)
      return futureAvailableResource.promise
    }

    const resourceId = this._resourceIds.dequeue()

    if (this._resources.length) {
      const { resource } = this._resources.dequeue()
      if (isDirty(resource)) {
        this._resourceIds.enqueue(resourceId)
        return this.resource()
      }
      return Promise.resolve(this._dispatchResource(resource, resourceId))
    }

    return this._createResource().then(resource => {
      return this._dispatchResource(resource, resourceId)
    })
  }

  private _dispatchResource (resource: any, resourceId: number) { 
    resource[POOL_ID] = resourceId
    this._issued[resourceId] = resource
    return resource
  }

  private _queuePossibleDestruction (resource :T) {
    this._resources.enqueue({ expiration: Date.now() + this._idle, resource })
    if (!this._timeoutToken) {
      this._scheduleNextCleanup(this._idle)
    }
  }

  private _cleanup () {
    if (this.size === this._min || !this._resources.length) {
      return this._timeoutToken = null
    }

    const { expiration } = this._resources.peekFront(),
      expiredMsAgo = expiration - Date.now()

    if (expiredMsAgo <= 0) {
      const { resource } = this._resources.dequeue()
      this.destroy(resource)
      this._scheduleNextCleanup(100)
    } else {
      this._scheduleNextCleanup(expiredMsAgo + 1)
    }
  }

  private _scheduleNextCleanup(ms: number) {
    if (!this._closing) {
      this._timeoutToken = setTimeout(() => {
        this._cleanup()    
      }, ms)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting use case! The core functionality reminds me a bit of my own [AsyncQueue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188795/blocking-promise-driven-queues-with-ecmascripts-async-await-and-generators) implementation.

I admittedly did not have too much of a look at your business logic, though. I hope the following notes are still of use for you.

- Use default values in the object destructuring

  ```
  constructor ({ createConnection, destroyConnection, idle, min, max }) {
    this._max = max || this._max
    this._min = min || this._min
    this._idle = idle || this._idle

  constructor ({
    createConnection, destroyConnection,
    idle = 30000,
    min = 0,
    max = 10
  }) {
  ```
- I would declare `size` to be a function than a getter property because it can and will return a varying value over the lifetime of your pool. A function call better conveys reading the current value whereas a property read might be mistaken for a onetime operation for reading a constant. Therefore, I find the getter properties for the other values like `max` and `min` to be a perfect fit!
  (Side note: why `Array#length` is not a function might also be disputable by the same argumentation.)
- Add parentheses where operator precedence is not totally clear

  ```
  // In drain
  !this._closing && setTimeout(wait, 100) || resolve()
  ```

  I would even go so far to prefer if-else-blocks instead of double-nested short-circuit logic here.
- Annotate functions returning a Promise with `async`.
  Currently, some functions have no return type annotation and return Promises on multiple branches. It would be quite easy to introduce another branch and return a raw value (e.g. `return this.size`) directly instead of wrapped inside a Promise. Using the type system effectively guards against these errors.