# Blocking Promise-driven queues with ECMAScript's async/await and generators

Tags: javascript, queue, promise, async-await, typescript

I implemented an `AsyncQueue`, whose `dequeue()` operation returns a Promise. The `AsyncLimitedQueue` additionally enforces a limit on the number of entries, so that `queue()` returns a Promise as well.

- Full code + unit tests: https://github.com/ComFreek/async-playground
- Generated documentation: https://comfreek.github.io/async-playground

Both classes use [`Semaphore`](https://github.com/ComFreek/async-playground/blob/master/semaphore/Semaphore.ts), which I also built using Promises. For the sake of brevity, I would like to restrain this question to the queue implementations.

### Usage example

Excerpt from https://github.com/ComFreek/async-playground/blob/master/examples/queue-stdio-lines.ts:

```
async function* readInput() {
    // null signals the end of input
    const queue: IAsyncQueue<string|null> = new AsyncQueue();
    // readline is an NPM package simplifying reading lines from stdio     
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ /* ... */ });

    rl.on('line', (line: string) => queue.queue(line));
    rl.on('close', () => queue.queue(null));

    yield* queue;
}

for await (const line of readInput()) {
    if (line === null) {
        break;
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

### Questions

- Have I followed best practices?
- Are the method contracts clean? Especially, have I employed asynchronous operations and promises where appropriate?
- Having both interfaces `IAsyncQueue` and `IAsyncLimitedQueue`, I intentionally did not create a common superinterface. Was this a right decision?

  The reason is that `IAsyncQueue#queue` and similar operations are synchronous and therefore non-blocking contrary to `IAsyncLimitedQueue#queue`, which is asynchronous.
  This difference is also manifested in their types, `void` vs `Promise<void>`. Making `AsyncQueue#queue` returning a Promise as well would violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), namely that it is synchronous despite its return type.

### Code

Online: [repo](https://github.com/ComFreek/async-playground), [docs](https://comfreek.github.io/async-playground)

**`AsyncQueue.ts`**

````
import { ISemaphore, Semaphore } from '../semaphore/index';

/**
 * Asynchronous FIFO queue with a Promise-driven dequeue operation.
 *
 * All element values are allowed, especially falsy ones, e.g.
 * false, 0, undefined, null, [], {} are all valid elements which
 * can be queued and dequeued.
 *
 * The {@link AsyncIterable} interface iterates the queue's (future) contents
 * ad infinitum. Users are advised to signal the end by manual insertion of a
 * special value (a so-called poison pill):
 *
 * ```
 * const queue = new AsyncQueue<string|null>();
 * file.on('data', (data) => queue.queue(data));
 * file.on('close', () => queue.queue(null));
 *
 * for await (const data of queue) {
 *   if (data === null) {
 *     break;
 *   }
 *   // Otherwise, process data
 * }
 * ```
 */
export interface IAsyncQueue<T> extends AsyncIterable<T> {
    /**
     * Queue an element immediately.
     */
    queue(data: T): void;

    /**
     * Queue all elements of an iterable, e.g. an array or a generator function.
     *
     * @example `queue.queueAll(['myArray', 'of', 'strings'])`
     *
     * @example If one has a generator function f:
     *          `function *f(): Iterable<string> { ... }`
     *          then you can call `queue.queueAll(f())`.
     */
    queueAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): void;

    /**
     * Queue all elements of an asynchronous iterable, e.g. an asynchronous
     * generator functions.
     *
     * @example Using an asynchronous generator function:
     * ```
     * async function *f(): AsyncIterable<string> {
     *   yield* ['Array', 'of', 'strings'];
     * }
     *
     * const previousSize = queue.size();
     * queue.queueAllAsync(f());
     * // ^ We do not await the queueing!
     * // Therefore: queue.size() === previousSize here!
     * // This is indeed guaranteed by JS' execution model. There is
     * // no way queueAllAsync could have queried an element from f()
     * // asynchronously using a promise before this code gives up
     * // the "CPU power" by await or yield.
     *
     * await queue.dequeue(); // 'Array'
     * await queue.dequeue(); // 'of'
     * await queue.dequeue(); // 'strings'
     *
     * // queue.size() === 0 and queue.dequeue() would block
     * // ad infinitum
     *
     * await queue.queueAllAsync(f());
     * // We now await the queueing!
     * // Therefore: queue.size() === 3 here!
     * ```
     *
     * @example AsyncQueue instances are also asynchronous iterables,
     *          meaning that you can stack multiple queues together:
     * ```
     * const backgroundQueue: IAsyncQueue<string> = new AsyncQueue();
     * const foregroundQueue: IAsyncQueue<string> = new AsyncQueue();
     *
     * setTimeout(() => backgroundQueue.queue('Hello World!'), 100);
     *
     * foregroundQueue.queueAllAsync(backgroundQueue);
     * const retrievedString = await foregroundQueue.dequeue();
     *
     * // retrievedString === 'Hello World!'
     * ```
     */
    queueAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Dequeue an element, waiting for data to be available if necessary.
     *
     * @returns A promise which is fulfilled when an element (as queued by
     *          queue()) becomes available.
     *          If multiple dequeus() are issued sequentially, it is
     *          implementation-defined whether they are fulfilled in the same
     *          order or not. However, the data is still retrieved in FIFO
     *          fashion, meaning the first fulfilled promise gets the first
     *          element, the second fulfilled the second one and so forth.
     */
    dequeue(): Promise<T>;

    /**
     * Dequeue an element if available or throw an exception otherwise.
     *
     * @returns The first element of the queue.
     * @throws An exception if the queue is empty at the time of the call.
     */
    poll(): T;

    /**
     * Return the current size at the moment of the call.
     *
     * Even though code like
     * ```
     * if (queue.size() >= 1) {
     *   const element = queue.poll();
     * }
     * ```
     * is technically not wrong (due to JS' execution model), users are
     * advised to avoid this pattern. Instead, users are encouraged to
     *
     *  - in cases where waiting for a promise is impossible, to use
     *    {@link poll} and catch the exception,
     *  - or to use {@link dequeue} with JS' `await` or
     *    `queue.dequeue().then(...)`.
     */
    size(): number;
}

export class NoElementError extends Error {
}

export class AsyncQueue<T> implements IAsyncQueue<T> {
    private buffer: T[] = [];
    private elementSem: ISemaphore = new Semaphore(0);

    public queue(data: T): void {
        this.buffer.push(data);
        this.elementSem.free();
    }

    public queueAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): void {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            this.queue(element);
        }
    }

    public async queueAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<void> {
        for await (const element of iterable) {
            this.queue(element);
        }
    }

    public async dequeue(): Promise<T> {
        await this.elementSem.take();

        try {
            return this.poll();
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof NoElementError) {
                throw new Error('AsyncQueue dequeue: poll() threw an exception \
 even though dequeue() waited for its element semaphore to be available via take().');
            }
            else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    }

    public poll(): T {
        if (this.buffer.length >= 1) {
            const dequeuedElement = this.buffer.shift();

            // Force-cast the element since we know that the buffer contains
            // at least one element and JS' execution model prohibits other
            // interleaving fibers to modify the buffer (=> no race condition).
            //
            // Also, we cannot check for shift() returning undefined as the queue
            // might well contain "undefined" as such.
            return (dequeuedElement as T);
        }
        else {
            throw new NoElementError();
        }
    }

    public size(): number {
        return this.buffer.length;
    }

    public async *[Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<T> {
        while (true) {
            yield this.dequeue();
        }
    }
}
````

**`AsyncLimitedQueue`**:

````
import { IAsyncQueue, AsyncQueue } from './AsyncQueue';
import { ISemaphore, Semaphore } from '../semaphore/index';

/**
 * Asynchronous entrance-limited FIFO queue with a Promise-driven dequeue operation.
 *
 * Contrary to {@link IAsyncQueue}, the queue operation is Promise-driven as well,
 * e.g. implementations might delay entrance into the queue, e.g. to enforce a
 * limit on the number of elements stored in the queue at the same time, cf.
 * {@link AsyncLimitedQueue}.
 * Other types of entrance limitations are conceivable as well, such as a
 * restriction on the sum of contained elements in case of a number queue.
 *
 * All element values are allowed, especially falsy ones, e.g.
 * false, 0, undefined, null, [], {} are all valid elements which
 * can be queued and dequeued.
 *
 * {@link queue IAsyncLimitedQueue#queue} operations are possibly delayed and
 * executed in implementation-dependenent order.
 *
 * @example Issueing multiple {@link queue} operations without awaiting the
 *          previous ones may result in implementation-defined insertion order.
 * ```
 * queue.queue(1);
 * queue.queue(2);
 *
 * await queue.dequeue(); // can be 1 or 2
 * await queue.dequeue(); // can be 1 or 2 as well (the remaining number)
 * ```
 *
 * @example If you would like to retain the order, await the {@link queue}
 *          operations, use {@link queueAll IAsyncLimitedQueue#queueAll} or
 *          {@link queueAllAsync IAsyncLimitedQueue#queueAllAsync}.
 * ```
 * await queue.queue(1);
 * await queue.queue(2);
 * ```
 * ```
 * queue.queueAll([1, 2]);
 * ```
 *
 * The {@link AsyncIterable} interface iterates the queue's (future) contents
 * ad infinitum. Users are advised to signal the end by manual insertion of a
 * special value (a so-called poison pill), see {@link IAsyncQueue}.
 */
export interface IAsyncLimitedQueue<T> extends AsyncIterable<T> {
    /**
     * Queue an element, waiting for entrance if necessary.
     *
     * @example
     * ```
     * queue.queue(42).then(() => {
     *   // 42 is now stored within the queue
     * });
     * ```
     */
    queue(data: T): Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Queue all elements of an iterable, e.g. an array or a generator function.
     * @see IAsyncQueue#queueAll
     */
    queueAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Queue all elements of an asynchronous iterable, e.g. an asynchronous
     * generator functions.
     *
     * @see IAsyncQueue#queueAllAsync
     */
    queueAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Offer an element, only queueing it if entrance is available at the time
     * of the call.
     *
     * @returns True if the element could be inserted right away. False
     *          otherwise.
     */
    offer(data: T): boolean;

    /**
     * Offer all elements of an iterable for in-order insertion.
     *
     * @param iterable An iterable whose first (limit - queue.size()) elements
     *                 will be inserted. Iterables which iterate an infinite
     *                 number of elements can also be passed and will *not*
     *                 result in an endless loop.
     *
     * @returns The number of elements, which could be inserted right away.
     *          Possibly 0 when the queue was full at the time of the call.
     */
    offerAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): number;

    /**
     * Offer all elements of an asynchronous iterable for in-order insertion.
     *
     * @param iterable An iterable whose elements will be {@link offer}ed
     *                 in-order for this queue.
     *                 The method will stop querying and offering further
     *                 elements upon the first {@link offer} call, which
     *                 returns `false`.
     *                 <br>
     *                 Contrary to {@link offerAll}, iterables iterating an
     *                 infinite number of elements might prevent the Promise,
     *                 which {@link offerAllAsync} returns, from ever resolving.
     *                 <br>
     *                 This depends on {@link dequeue} operations which could
     *                 get scheduled by the JS VM while elements from the passed
     *                 asynchronous iterator are accessed.
     *
     * @returns A promise resolving to the number of elements, which could be
     *          inserted (offered successfully) consecutively without waiting.
     *          Possibly 0 when the queue was full at the time of the call.
     *          Fulfillment of this promise is not guaranteed in case of infinite
     *          iterables.
     */
    offerAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<number>;

    /**
     * Dequeue an element if available or throw an exception otherwise.
     *
     * @returns The first element of the queue.
     * @throws An exception if the queue is empty at the time of the call.
     */
    poll(): T;

    /**
     * Dequeue an element, waiting for data to be available if necessary.
     *
     * @returns A promise which is fulfilled when an element (as queued by
     *          queue()) becomes available.
     *          If multiple dequeus() are issued sequentially, it is
     *          implementation-defined whether they are fulfilled in the same
     *          order or not. However, the data is still retrieved in FIFO
     *          fashion, meaning the first fulfilled promise gets the first
     *          element, the second fulfilled the second one and so forth.
     */
    dequeue(): Promise<T>;

    /**
     * Return the current size at the moment of the call.
     *
     * Even though code like
     * ```
     * if (queue.size() >= 1) {
     *   const element = queue.poll();
     * }
     * ```
     * is technically not wrong (due to JS' execution model), users are
     * advised to avoid this pattern. Instead, users are encouraged to
     *
     *  - in cases where waiting for a promise is impossible, to use
     *    {@link poll} and catch the exception,
     *  - or to use {@link dequeue} with JS' `await` or
     *    `queue.dequeue().then(...)`.
     */
    size(): number;
}

/**
 * Asynchronous element-limited FIFO queue with a Promise-driven dequeue operation.
 *
 * {@link AsyncLimitedQueue#queue} operations are delayed (in unspecified order)
 * until space becomes available through dequeue operations.
 */
export class AsyncLimitedQueue<T> implements IAsyncLimitedQueue<T> {
    private limitSem: ISemaphore;

    /**
     * Initialize the queue.
     * @param limit A integer >= 1 specifying the number of elements after which
     *              queue() effectively blocks (i.e. the promise returned by it
     *              does not get "immediately" fulfilled for some informal value
     *              of immediately).
     * @param storageQueue An asynchronous (non-limiting) queue backing the data.
     *                     It defaults to a AsyncQueue.
     *
     * @throws An exception in case the limit is not an integer or is <= 0.
     */
    public constructor(limit: number, private storageQueue: IAsyncQueue<T> = new AsyncQueue()) {
        if (!Number.isInteger(limit) || limit <= 0) {
            throw new Error('AsyncLimitedQueue: Illegal limit (non-integer or\
 <= 0) on queued elements. It must be an integer >= 1.');
        }
        this.limitSem = new Semaphore(limit);
    }

    public async queue(data: T): Promise<void> {
        await this.limitSem.take();
        this.storageQueue.queue(data);
    }

    public async queueAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): Promise<void> {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            await this.queue(element);
        }
    }

    public async queueAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<void> {
        for await (const element of iterable) {
            await this.queue(element);
        }
    }

    public offer(data: T): boolean {
        if (this.limitSem.tryTake()) {
            this.storageQueue.queue(data);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public offerAll(iterable: Iterable<T>): number {
        let insertedElements = 0;

        for (const element of iterable) {
            if (!this.offer(element)) {
                return insertedElements;
            }

            insertedElements++;
        }

        return insertedElements;
    }

    public async offerAllAsync(iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<number> {
        let insertedElements = 0;

        for await (const element of iterable) {
            if (!this.offer(element)) {
                return insertedElements;
            }

            insertedElements++;
        }

        return insertedElements;
    }

    public async dequeue(): Promise<T> {
        return this.storageQueue.dequeue().then(element => {
            this.limitSem.free();
            return element;
        });
    }

    public poll(): T {
        return this.storageQueue.poll();
    }

    public async *[Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<T> {
        while (true) {
            yield this.dequeue();
        }
    }

    public size(): number {
        return this.storageQueue.size();
    }
}
````